best option if I want to transfer .pgp and .zip files from FTP to Azure Blob Storage repeatedly
What is the best option if I want to transfer .pgp and .zip files from FTP to Azure Blob Storage repeatedly?
We have multiple FTP configurations, which are stored in the Snowflake database. We can connect to FTP using their credentials.

This is not a programming question.

A very simple approach would be to use Azure Logic Apps for repeated copy operations from FTP to BLOB. It should be easy to set up without any coding required.
If you want more control and write the code yourself I'd go with time triggered Azure Functions.

The credentials for FTP are saved in the Snowflake DB, and there is a chance of increasing the number of clients in the future. Which approach will have the least impact?
